# How to only draw the body points and connection without the face

Tags: python, mediapipe

I am using mediapipe, I want to just draw the body with the connection and the point but removing the connection and the point from the face.

```
import cv2            
import mediapipe as mp  
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector 

mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils 
mpPose = mp.solutions.pose  
pose = mpPose.Pose()       

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("segment4_pumping_and_foiling.mp4") 

while True:    
  success, img = cap.read()  
  
  results = pose.process(img) 

  if results.pose_landmarks:  #if it finds the points
    for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark): 
        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS) 

  cv2.imshow("video", img)  
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
    break   

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not that easy to do.

The way you are calling the draw utility passes two arguments to it - pose landmarks and pose connections.

[Pose landmarks](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/python/solutions/pose.py) are listed here. It is just an enum which goes like so:

```
  NOSE = 0
  LEFT_EYE_INNER = 1
  LEFT_EYE = 2
```

And so on, with 33 points total. Similarly, `POSE_CONNECTIONS` is defined [here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/710fb3de58dc10b7bc75f9cb758300c9016a5e4f/mediapipe/python/solutions/pose_connections.py):

```
POSE_CONNECTIONS = frozenset([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 7), (0, 4), (4, 5),
                              (5, 6), (6, 8), (9, 10), (11, 12), (11, 13),
                              (13, 15), (15, 17), (15, 19), (15, 21), (17, 19),
                              (12, 14), (14, 16), (16, 18), (16, 20), (16, 22),
                              (18, 20), (11, 23), (12, 24), (23, 24), (23, 25),
                              (24, 26), (25, 27), (26, 28), (27, 29), (28, 30),
                              (29, 31), (30, 32), (27, 31), (28, 32)])
```

Correspondingly, you could set the visibility field on landmarks corresponding to all points on the face (basically, IDs <= 10) below the default threshold of 0.5:

```
for landmark in results.pose_landmarks.landmark:  
        landmark.visibility = 0
```

and use a different custom list of connections similar to `POSE_CONNECTIONS` above:

```
MY_CONNECTIONS = frozenset([t for t in mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS if t[0] > 10 and t[1] > 10])
```

Putting it all together:

```
import cv2            
import mediapipe as mp  
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector 

mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils 
mpPose = mp.solutions.pose  
pose = mpPose.Pose()  
CUTOFF_THRESHOLD = 10  # head and face    
MY_CONNECTIONS = frozenset([t for t in mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS if t[0] > CUTOFF_THRESHOLD and t[1] > CUTOFF_THRESHOLD])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("segment4_pumping_and_foiling.mp4") 

while True:    
    success, img = cap.read()  
    results = pose.process(img) 

    if results.pose_landmarks:  # if it finds the points
        for landmark_id, landmark in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks):
            if landmark_id <= CUTOFF_THRESHOLD:
                landmark.visibility = 0
        mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, MY_CONNECTIONS) 

    cv2.imshow("video", img)  
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break   

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cap.release()
```

I have not tested it, admittedly, as full reproduction requires a little bit too involved of a setup, but [draw_landmarks](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/python/solutions/drawing_utils.py#L119) function does not leave that much of a wiggle room, either...